# How do I compute a grand total in ORACLE?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT f.flight_id,
       COUNT(b.Booking_ID) As "Total SeatPurchased",
       COUNT(b.Booking_ID)*flight_price 
FROM   booking b , flight f
WHERE  b.flight_id=f.flight_id 
GROUP BY f.flight_id,f.flight_price
ORDER BY COUNT(b.booking_id) desc;
```

How do I compute the grand total for this sql? I want to calculate all the flightPrice and at the end of the whole thing. I want to sum up all as the grand total.

Sample Output:

```
FLIGHT_ID  Total Seat Purchased  COUNT(B.BOOKING_ID)*FLIGHT_PRICE 
-----------------------------------------------------------------
F0006                       149                            11771                
F0011                       148                            38332                
F0012                       131                            11528                
F0003                       130                            33670                
F0010                       115                            10120                
F0004                       113                             8362                
F0005                       108                             7992                
F0007                       101                             7373                
F0015                        80                            11200                
F0002                        50                             5700                
F0008                        41                             8774                
F0013                        36                             8316                
F0001                        35                             6265                
F0014                        35                             7490                
F0009                        35                             4690  
                                               Grandtotal:xxxxxx
```

Comment: added example output in the main thread

Answer (score 0):

Try this then:

> COMPUTE SUM OF COUNT(b.Booking_ID)*flight_price  ON REPORT

```
SELECT f.flight_id,COUNT(b.Booking_ID) As "Total SeatPurchased", COUNT(b.Booking_ID)*flight_price 
FROM booking b , flight f
WHERE b.flight_id=f.flight_id 
--    GROUP BY ROLLUP ( f.flight_id,f.flight_price )
GROUP BY  f.flight_id,f.flight_price 
ORDER BY COUNT(b.booking_id) DESC;
```

Comment: I want the grand total of the whole column of flightprice*count(booking_Id),I tried using this code and it is not the desired result I want

Comment: @user3903563: This better perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

To get grantotal value just use this:

```
    SUM(COUNT(B.BOOKING_ID)*FLIGHT_PRICE)
```

Comment: i get "not a single group group function" error when I add this code into the Select clause there

Comment: add this: GROUP BY f.flight_id,f.flight_price,b.Booking_ID

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work for you:

```
SELECT f.flight_id,COUNT(b.Booking_ID) As "Total SeatPurchased",
       COUNT(b.Booking_ID)*flight_price, 
       (SELECT SUM(FlightPrice)
          FROM (  SELECT f.flight_id,
                         COUNT(b.Booking_ID) As "Total SeatPurchased",
                         COUNT(b.Booking_ID)*flight_price As FlightPrice 
                    FROM booking b , flight f
                   WHERE b.flight_id=f.flight_id 
                GROUP BY f.flight_id,f.flight_price)) As "Grand Total"
 FROM booking b , flight f
WHERE b.flight_id=f.flight_id 
GROUP BY f.flight_id,f.flight_price
ORDER BY COUNT(b.booking_id) desc;
```

I'm not using Oracle at the moment so I can't test it.  I'm pretty sure this isn't going to be very efficient so you might want to consider working out the grand total from the calling code, if possible.

**Update 1**

```
(SELECT f.flight_id,COUNT(b.Booking_ID) As "Total SeatPurchased",
       COUNT(b.Booking_ID)*flight_price
 FROM booking b , flight f
WHERE b.flight_id=f.flight_id 
GROUP BY f.flight_id,f.flight_price
ORDER BY COUNT(b.booking_id) desc)
UNION
SELECT null, 
       null, 
       SUM(FlightPrice)
  FROM (  SELECT f.flight_id,
                 COUNT(b.Booking_ID) As "Total SeatPurchased",
                 COUNT(b.Booking_ID)*flight_price As FlightPrice 
            FROM booking b , flight f
           WHERE b.flight_id=f.flight_id 
        GROUP BY f.flight_id,f.flight_price)
```

I think this is what you are after but it doesn't seem a very good idea to add the grand total as an extra row.  I'd still recommend working out the grand total from the calling code.

Comment: i get the grand total but it appear on every row.How do I make it appear only at the most bottom row?